# Moving Fiddle from Dashboard to Public

Tags: jsfiddle

So, I feel a bit silly asking this, but I can't find anything in the docs. I have one fiddle under my *Public Fiddles*, and several under *Dashboard*.

How do I move a fiddle from *Dashboard* to *Public Fiddles*?

Comment: Also, be sure that you've saved your info in <USER-NAME> | Personal Settings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to make a jsfiddle public it needs to have both a title and be set as the base version.

To set it as the base version, select *'Fork'* on the menu. The forked fiddle will have an additional menu item *'Base'* (indicating that it's the base version).

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer

Comment: Yeah this seemed to do the trick for me. Not that obvious in the fiddle UI huh

Answer (score 6):

Add a title to the fiddle (via Fiddle Options on the left sidebar); this makes the fiddle public.
(It may take a few minutes to take effect.)

Comment: I tried this. It did not move the fiddle into [Public Fiddles]. Its just a named fiddle on my Dashboard

Comment: Seems like a problem on our end, but this is the way it worked.

Comment: Hmm. Is it working for you now?

Comment: Not working for me, either. I created a fiddle, gave it a title, then clicked on "Your Public Fiddles" and it said I don't have any fiddles yet.

Comment: @OskarKrawczyk Any update on the issue? I am still unable to set fiddle public. Thanks!

Comment: Chaya Cooper's answer is more correct

Comment: @mika - This solution doesn't seem to work for most users :-( Have you tried the method that I posted below?

Comment: @ChayaCooper It actually seems to work after a few minutes.

Comment: @Mika - That's great :-) It might be helpful to future users if you edited the answer with a note to that effect :-)

Comment: any idea how to search for public fiddles - I'm looking for working examples and it seems that public only means you can access it? is there a way to search all public fiddles???

Answer (score 0):

On the left nav go to "Fiddle meta" to create a title and description. It worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Try to open the fiddle with the "share" URL while logged out (using a different browser is usually faster).

Comment: But does it work, while trying?